# one subdomain won't load on my local network, but the other will

Tags: .htaccess, http, subdomain

http://client.henrybuilt.com/ - won't load on my network (network meaning internet connection) (even though i can load it on other networks)

http://presentation.henrybuilt.com/ - loads on any network

Both have the same settings in my control panel.

My htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^client.henrybuilt.com
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subClient/
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subClient/$1 [L]

RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^presentation.henrybuilt.com
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !presentation/
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ presentation/$1 [L]
```

Can anyone duplicate the issue or explain it?

I know it's not very much information to go off of, but I thought maybe someone would know of a method of debugging it.

Comment: well if the sub domain was created recently then you may need to allow up to 48 hours for the DNS to update, and if u keep accessing it the cache won't go away. Usually depending on your provider it may take less than 5 minutes to get the DNS to update but can take up to 48 hours. **Ping the sub domain from the accessible location and the non accessible location and see if the IP's are the same.**

Comment: it was created a year and a half ago. ping tells me it is at the correct ip when accessible but when not it says cant find host

Comment: How is your network ? do you have perchance an internal DNS or it comes from provider ? Have you tried to monitor the sub domain from both points to see if it stops responding to pings or HTTP requests between any period of time and for how long ? I would start with this, if it goes off only at your end, monitor it with HTTP request and see if there is a pattern of time of when it happens, then if it only happens on once of the points you null the option of your server being down, so it could be your provider having issues with routing or connectivity or similar. You can use pingdom.com.

Comment: But the ideal is to also have a small application monitoring the requests from each points something like [**PingPlotter**](http://www.pingplotter.com/) would be ideal as it will monitor not only the IP and ping but the entire trace between you and the location which u will have a more detailed information about if your routing changes, when, why, if you're getting dropped request, the time response and more.

Comment: a proxy server allows me to load the website. I don't know if that helps at all

Comment: a proxy server does not rely on your provider IP/DNS AFAIK, so it doesn't really help on debugging where the issue is using ping plotter as I mentioned early you see exactly where you stop reaching the IP and define why.

Comment: it just said host not found. www.client.henrybuilt.com was the url i used

Comment: client.henrybuilt.com = exist / www.client.henrybuilt.com = does not exist.

Comment: You can further check the cPanel and look for the domain DNS entries.